# Implementing Read Only view in Winform App

Tags: .net, winforms, controls, readonly

I have an in house winform app for viewing, editing, and inserting member data.  There are about 40 sepertate form pages that they use to manipulate different portions of the data.

My question is this; What is the best way of implementing a read only view for a form page?

My thoughts were to 
cycle through the controls setting `Enabled = False` 
or
leave them be but not allow any data changes(no Save Button etc) unless it is "unlocked".

I am curious how others handle this with WinForm apps?

Comment: Please note: ReadOnly != Disabled.

Answer (score 1):

I think that if a field is not meant to be edited, it shouldn't look like a field. Making it look like a field gives the user the **visual queue** that it should be editable. They may wonder why it's not. So instead of `Enabled=False`, why don't you make the readonly fields labels?

**Update:** An alternative if you have to keep them Text fields is to style them to look like labels. This would mean making their background color gray, removing the border and removing the tabstop. You could create a `DisableField` function to do this.

Comment: Not sure this is feasible for our setup.  I'd have to swap out `labels` for `textboxes` whenever they wanted to edit the information.

Comment: Yes, it's a better user experience. Otherwise, users tend to ask "how can I enable that field ?"...

Comment: so you would have multiple forms based on the current user.  If they only currently have Read-Only then shown them `frmMemberReadOnly`.  If they currently have Full permissions then show them an entirely different form(`frmMemberFull`) with editable controls....

Answer (score 1):

If your data-binding does not support readonly, then Yes, write some code to make the UI readonly as far as possible. But that is not 'safe' so be sure to block any commands that could trigger an update.

You want it readonly to be consistent, don't allow users to edit a Field they cannot save. But don't set Enabled=false everywhere, that behaves different (no select/copy etc).

And think about comboboxes, do you want them to be able to drop-down?

Comment: Standard windows databinding supports read-only?  Are you saying in your second paragraph that I should monitor each fields click_event and check if it is currently "read-only"?

Comment: I don't know what form of data-binding you use... could be manual. And No, don't add events to all controls, just makes sure the main logic for saving blocks.

Answer (score 0):

It might be better to say it this way, if the fields on the form are read-only, then replace them with labels which are not editable. This will be more suited for textboxes, checkboxes, as for combo-boxes and list-boxes, perhaps, you will have to give them a label also, by showing the selection used in both cases as labels - what do you think?

In fact, here are some links that will enable you to retain the combo-box/listboxes if you wish to avoid making the selections as labels...

- An article on implementing a readonly combo-box is on [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/combobox/ReadOnlyComboBoxByClaudio.aspx)
- The only gotcha is the combo-box will not look exactly polished if readonly, this article on [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/combobox/disabledcombodisplay.aspx) shows how to make it more polished.
- A readonly combobox (VB.NET) using the IExtendedProvider here on [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/combobox/ReadOnly_Combo_Provider.aspx)
- A Listbox combined with a checkbox used as a readonly listbox here on [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/combobox/CheckListBox.aspx)
- How to disable the checkbox but not the scrollbar here on [Social.MSDN.Microsoft.com](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winforms/thread/c34a51b1-a597-4534-842d-1a2d243367e9/)
- An article on listbox with disabled items here on [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/combobox/DisabledListbox.aspx)